# How to delete points with the same information (housenumber) but different position within polygons (buildings) and keeping just one in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-2.8

I´m working with shape files. I have one point layer with house numbers, which I want to de shown over the polygon layer buildings. My Problem is that almost every builing has got 2 or more points with the same number. I want to keep just one. But there are also points within some buildings with different information e.g. house number 2a, 2b, 2c and this should stay like it is.

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Tomas! Try using the **Dissolve** tool on your point layer and select the field which contains the house numbers. Then label the output layer.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn´t work. I have many different streets, like that it would keep just one. The dataset has more than 27000 house numbers (points) and the number 1 e.g. is 1100 times in my data. If I would split the data by the field number, I cuold dissolve using the field street name. But than I would have the problem that some street names like "Hauptstraße" or "Kirchstraße" in different villages having the same name.